# Need to calculate standard deviation from an array using bash and awk?

Tags: bash, awk, gawk

Guys I'm new to awk and I'm struggling with awk command to find the standard deviation.

I have got the mean using the following:

```
echo ${GfieldList[@]} | awk 'NF {sum=0;for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)sum+=$i; print "Mean= " sum / NF; }'
```

Standard Deviation formula is:

```
sqrt((1/N)*(sum of (value - mean)^2))
```

I have found the mean using the above formula

Can you guys help me with the awk command for this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you know the mean:

```
awk '{
    for (i = 1;i <= NF; i++) {
        sum += $i
    };
    print sum / NF
}' # for 2, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 7, 9 gives 5
```

then the standard deviation can be found thus:

```
awk -vM=5 '{
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        sum += ($i-M) * ($i-M)
    };
    print sqrt (sum / NF)
}' # for 2, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 7, 9 gives 2
```

In "compressed" form:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){sum+=$i};print sum/NF}'
awk -vM=5 '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){sum+=($i-M)*($i-M)};print sqrt(sum/NF)}'
```

(changing the value for `M` to the actual mean extracted from the first command).

Comment: Hi thanks very much paxidiablo!  I need to save the mean in a variable.

Comment: mean = echo{array[@]} | awk '{
    for (i = 1;i <= NF; i++) {
        sum+=$i
    };
    print sum/NF
}

Answer (score 4):

An alternate formula for the [standard deviation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation) is the square root of the quantity: (the mean square minus the square of the mean).  This is used below:

```
$ echo 20 21 22 | awk 'NF {sum=0;ssq=0;for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){sum+=$i;ssq+=$i**2}; print "Std Dev=" (ssq/NF-(sum/NF)**2)**0.5}'
Std Dev=0.816497
```

Notes:

- In `awk`, `NF` is the number of "fields" on a line.  In our case, every field is a number, so `NF` is the number of numbers on a given line.
- `ssq` is the sum of the squares of each number on the line.  Thus, `ssq/NF` is the mean square.
- `sum` is the sum of the numbers on the line.  Thus `sum/NF` is the mean and  `(sum/NF)**2` is the square of the mean.
- As per the formular, then, the standard deviation is `(ssq/NF-(sum/NF)**2)**0.5`.

#### The `awk` code

- `NF`

  This serves as a condition: the statements which follow will only be executed if the number of fields on this line, NF, evaluates to true, meaning non-zero.  In other words, this condition will cause empty lines to be skipped.
- `sum=0;ssq=0;`

  This initializes `sum` and `ssq` to zero. This is only needed if there is more than one line of input.
- `for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){sum+=$i;ssq+=$i**2}`

  This puts the sum of all the numbers in `sum` and the sum of the square of the numbers in `ssq`.
- `print "Std Dev=" (ssq/NF-(sum/NF)**2)**0.5`

  This prints out the standard deviation.